# Extract pattern "number / number"

Tags: r, regex

I would like to extract blood pressures from string. The data might look like this:

```
text <- c("at 10.00 seated 132/69", "99/49", "176/109",  
"10.12 I 128/51, II 149/51 h.9.16", "153/82 p.90 ja 154/81 p.86", 
"h:17.45", "not measured", "time 7.30 RR 202/97 p. 69")
```

I would like to extract pattern "number/number" (i.e. `"132/69"`). In the above example the expected output would be a list:

```
[[1]]
[1] "132/69" 

[[2]]
[1] "99/49"

[[3]]
[1] "176/109"

[[4]]
[1] "128/51" "149/51"

[[5]]
[1] "153/82" "154/81" 

[[6]]
[1] ""

[[7]]
[1] ""

[[8]]
[1] "202/97"
```

The closest solution that I have:

```
gsub( "^.*([0-9]{3}/[0-9]+).*","\\1", text)
```

Unfortunately, in my solution it does not return all matched cases of that pattern and also returns a string that does not have required pattern at all.

Comment: Will `library(stringr)`, `str_extract_all(text, "\\d+/\\d+")` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
regmatches(text, gregexpr("\\d+/\\d+", text))
#[[1]]
#[1] "132/69"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "99/49"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "176/109"
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "128/51" "149/51"
#
#[[5]]
#[1] "153/82" "154/81"
#
#[[6]]
#character(0)
#
#[[7]]
#character(0)
#
#[[8]]
#[1] "202/97"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get the exact output you described, you can use

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
text <- c("at 10.00 seated 132/69", "99/49", "176/109",  
          "10.12 I 128/51, II 149/51 h.9.16", "153/82 p.90 ja 154/81 p.86", 
          "h:17.45", "not measured", "time 7.30 RR 202/97 p. 69")

str_extract_all(text, "\\d{2,3}/\\d{1,3}") %>%
  lapply(FUN = function(x) if (length(x) == 0) "" else x)

[[1]]
[1] "132/69"

[[2]]
[1] "99/49"

[[3]]
[1] "176/109"

[[4]]
[1] "128/51" "149/51"

[[5]]
[1] "153/82" "154/81"

[[6]]
[1] ""

[[7]]
[1] ""

[[8]]
[1] "202/97"
```

You could also use Roland's `regmatches` if you want to stay in base R.

Answer (score 1):

A slight & more compact tangent to @Benjamin's solution that returns a nice, plain character vector and avoiding the need to deal with 0-length elements in @Roland's list:

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

txt <- c("at 10.00 seated 132/69", "99/49", "176/109",  
         "10.12 I 128/51, II 149/51 h.9.16", "153/82 p.90 ja 154/81 p.86", 
         "h:17.45", "not measured", "time 7.30 RR 202/97 p. 69")

stri_match_all_regex(txt, "\\d{2,3}/\\d{1,3}") %>%
  flatten_chr() %>% 
  discard(is.na)
## [1] "132/69"  "99/49"   "176/109" "128/51"  "149/51"  "153/82"  "154/81"  "202/97"
```